# JS function create multiple div when running with new data

Tags: javascript, html, anychart

I am really new to HTML and working on this simple task for hours.

I have dynamic data that use it to create a word cloud, the problem is when data changes, my js function make a new div and therefore a new word cloud but I want to update the last one, something look dynamic.

here is my js code:

```
function foo(){
    <!--some other things-->
   anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
   var chart = anychart.tagCloud(word_cloud);
   chart.title('Word relevancy map')
   chart.angles([0])
   chart.container("container");
   chart.draw();
    });
}
```

and my HTML container is like this:

```
<div id="container"  class="col-lg-8"  width=" 100%" height="800">
```

any help is appreciated<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to recreate the chart completely to update the data. The best practice here is to apply new data to the existing chart. For details check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/pJ3LbhFO).